# how to add bulk users to existing rally project under different workspace?

Tags: rest, rally, code-rally

we are migrating project from one work space to another work space ,we want to add users to particular projects.I tried through UI we can add only  single user at once or we need to copy users from different project under same work space but in my case i have two different work space.so I'm looking for web service call where i can pass json body and add user to the existing projects.

I'm trying with below service is it correct?

https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/user/create

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest following up with Rally support on this one.  Data moving/copying can be a pretty big project.  That being said, I'm pretty sure there are some scripts out there that make bulk user operations a little easier.  I don't know all the details, but they should be able to help you out.